# How to change formatting of stripe card-element based on viewport size

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, stripe-payments

I'm building an adaptive website using stripe for payments, including the Stripe `card-element`, which is used to accept credit card payments.

Naturally, with changing viewport size, the paragraph font size changes. The same should be true for the Stripe `card-element` which I am creating with `var card = elements.create('card')`. The Stripe card element is an iframe because the payment data goes straight to Stripe's servers, not mine, meaning that relative font sizing using `em` does not work and neither do media queries. Because, of course, this iframe doesn't care at all about my CSS, all the formatting instructions are currently passed to `stripe.elements.create` as I instantiate the card element.

How can I make style properties (in this case the font size) of the Stripe element adaptive?

The only way I can think of is checking for viewport size in JS and re-instantiating the element when the viewport size changes; but this seems ugly and overkill.

```js
var card = stripe.elements.create('card', {
  hidePostalCode: true,
  style: {
    base: {
      fontSize: "1em"
    }
  }
});

card.mount('#card-element');
```

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  p {
    font-size: 9pt;
    }
  #card-element {
    font-size: 9pt; // Does not work.
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  p {
    font-size: 12pt;
    }
  #card-element {
    font-size: 12pt; // Does not work.
    }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Some text preceding the card element</p>
  <div id="card-element"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

The `card` element has an `update` method that can be used to pass to it the same options as when first creating it. By using an event listener with the `update` methods, one can change the font-size in just the same way as it was first defined.

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
  if (window.innerWidth <= 320) {
    card.update({style: {base: {fontSize: '13px'}}});
  } else {
    card.update({style: {base: {fontSize: '16px'}}});
  }
});
```

Source: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#other-methods

Comment: When I try to do it from my css, It doesnt work. #card-element{ font-size:1rem;}